# Optimize INSERT performance with a UNIQUE constraint on md5(JSONB_COLUMN::text)

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, insert, postgresql-12

I have the following table and indices defined:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
    id serial,
    job_id bigint NOT NULL,
    payload jsonb NOT NULL,
    tags jsonb NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_data_content on data (md5(payload::text));
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_data_tags ON data USING GIN (tags jsonb_path_ops);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_data_jid ON data USING btree (job_id);
```

In that table, I store many JSON blobs, which are associated with a `job_id` (also available in `payload->>'jobId'`) and a time stamp (unix epoch) stored in `payload->>'__time'`. I want to avoid storing duplicate JSON blobs, so I'm using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53149623/169748) as a `UNIQUE` constraint. After a few hundred thousand rows in the DB, however, `INSERT` performance starts to decline, which does not happen without the `UNIQUE` constraint.

It is highly unlikely but possible to have two different JSON blobs with the *same* `job_id` *and* `payload->>'__time'`. Is there any way I can make use of that, for example, by defining a `UNIQUE` constraint that first checks the `job_id`, then `payload->>'__time'`, and only if both match actually checks the `md5(payload::text)` index?

(Note, that the keys in my JSON blobs are always in the same order for the same documents.)

Comment: Do you really need to consider **all** keys of the JSON value for uniqueness? Can't you pick two or three and then create an index on just those?

Comment: Well, it is possible (but very unlikely) that two different JSON blobs share the same `job_id` and `__time`. In addition, aside from having the fields `job_id` and `__time`, the JSON blobs can have very different keys/structures.

Comment: If I were you, I would drop the uniqueness requirement on the `jsonb`. Did you measure that it that index is actually at fault for the slowdown? It might well be the GIN index. See [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-tips.html) for more.

Comment: "After a few hundred thousand rows in the DB, however, INSERT performance starts to decline" - could you elaborate on what this looks like? calculating the md5 for each payload will remain the same regardless of table size, and inserting into a btree of only a few hundred thousand nodes should be quite fast.

Comment: @JohnBachir: Thank you for your comment. Indeed, the issues disappeared after I tuned the PGSQL Memory parameters (and reduced the size of the JSON blobs a little bit). I guess that the md5 index didn't fit in memory after a certain number of elements, which decreased performance. Now that everything seems to perform fine, I believe that the initial way of having a btree index for the md5 hash is the cleanest and least complex one.

Answer (score 1):

If the uniqueness constraint is the only issue (and I'm interested to learn more about why in the discussion above), here's an idea:

- remove the uniqueness constraint
- when you do reads (selects), do `order by id asc limit 1` so that you ignore duplicates
- have some sort of parallel process going through the table periodically and removing duplicates

Comment: Hi John, thank you for the suggestion. I'd rather have a clean table (in that it doesn't contain duplicate rows), though, than doing deduplication on select. This keeps the table from growing too much when old rows are (accidentally) re-inserted etc.

Answer (score 1):

here are a couple of ideas.
   One does the constraint check in a function.
   the second modifies the table, creates a trigger to add in the missing data and creates a new index on the three fields that have to be checked

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_jsonb
    BEFORE INSERT  
    ON data
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE 

CREATE FUNCTION public._check_jsonb()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
AS $BODY$
    declare

    _check_rec record;

    begin
        select job_id, payload from data where job_id = new.job_id 
        if found then
            if _check.payload.__time == new.jsonb.__time  
                  --do not know json command in postgresql 
                  -- that well to extract this value
                select true from data where new.payload == (md5(payload::text)) 
            end if;
        end if ;
        return new;
$BODY$
```

--Second Idea to try

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
    id serial,
    job_id bigint NOT NULL,
    payload jsonb NOT NULL,
    tags jsonb NULL,
    hash_check text not null, 
    time timestamp not null 
);
create unique index if not exists idx_jobid_time on data (id, time, hash_check);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_data_tags ON data USING GIN (tags jsonb_path_ops);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_data_jid ON data USING btree (job_id);

CREATE TRIGGER check_jsonb_idea2
    BEFORE INSERT  or Update
    ON data
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE 

CREATE FUNCTION public._check_jsonb_idea2()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
AS $BODY$
    begin 
        new.time = new.jsonb.__time ;-- do not know json commands very while extract this 
        new.hash_check = (md5(payload::text)) 
        return new;
    end;
$BODY$
```

This may also allow removing the other indexes

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The issue somewhat disappeared, though, by tuning the PGSQL memory parameters and I'm sticking with the simple md5() way now. See my comment to the question.